# googledrive html file only preview code

Tags: html, google-drive-api, publish

I am new to html5 and am currently working with the example on the web page listed below:
http://www.mobilehtml5.com/post/371921120/tutorial-your-first-mobile-html5-app-the-basics

To host the html page, I chose to use Google Drive as I already use it for other documents. To set it up, I followed the instructions on this page:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

I created a new folder under my google drive called 'New Folder' and set the permissions to 'Public on the web'. I created a file called 'index.html' on my local hard drive and put the example html code into it, then uploaded that file into my google drive under 'New Folder'.

The problem:
The page @ support.google.com says that to view the html page, one must click on 'preview'. However, when I do that, all I get to see is my code, not the rendered page. Also, the google support page says there is a URL like googledrive.com/host/... but my URL is different. When I click on my index.html file it shows the code and the URL is https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo&authuser=0#folders/....

Please help. I found the google support page very high level.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to your "Public on the web folder"

2) The url should look something like: drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/xx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

3) Instead of the "xx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" you should have a folder ID (it'll be random letters and numbers)

4) Replace the "xx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" in the following link with the folder ID from step 3)
googledrive.com/host/xx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/myHTMLFile.html

5) There's one last step. Replace the "myHTMLFile.html" at the end of this step with the name of your html file name.

See more in picture
https://www.facebook.com/posteryucom/photos/a.503819206368192.1073741827.124941240922659/704847832931994/?type=3&theater

https://www.facebook.com/posteryucom/photos/a.503819206368192.1073741827.124941240922659/704843842932393/?type=3&theater